# Recreate the Google+ navigation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, google-plus, recreate

I am currently trying to recreate the google+ navigation to the left, where you can switch your streams.

I have got everything working except the functionality to show the menu opened at page reload , if the page that is being reloaded is part of the navigation items, which otherwise would be hidden by default.

Does anybody have an idea, how they are doing it and how to recreate the functionality using jquery?

Thnx!

Comment: Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net/ to what you have so far?

Comment: A simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/njKmz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea I'd try is using `window.location.hash` to both set your current location, and, on reload, figure out which set of elements should be expanded. When you cascade out a new menu, set the hash like so:

```
window.location.hash = '#whatever';
```

Then on reload, check the hash:

```
if (window.location.hash != "")
{
    if (window.location.hash == '#whatever')
    {
        load_whatever_set();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, yes this seems to be the most practicable solution. Thanks!